# PowerShell command not run via cmd script

Tags: powershell, command-line

Here see the script, the last command should works, i mean everything's ok and it works when i run in windows Powershell.
But when i join that with 2 first commands which are bash scripts, the powershell's one won't run:

```
Net user administrator /active:yes

Net user administrator Hardware123

Set-LocalUser -Name "administrator" -PasswordNeverExpires 1
```

Comment: Where are you joining and where you are executing your bash.. how you are calling the powershell command in bash? you need to call powershell first and then need to execute the ps commands. these are cmd prompt's command in windows, not linux bash you are referring to.

Comment: powershell knows how to run statements meant for cmd and powershell itself but cmd / batch does **not** know anything about powershell commands. You have to execute powershell commands in powershell.

Comment: @Jawad
how about cmd ?
can i use cmd directly to run powerShell commands?

Comment: Does the answer below solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call powershell commands from a cmd / batch file, use the following syntax. You have to call powershell to be able to run powershell commands,

```
Net user administrator /active:yes
Net user administrator Hardware123
powershell.exe Set-LocalUser -Name "administrator" -PasswordNeverExpires 1
```

This is with assumption that you already have admin access to perform the above script.

You can also run multiple commands with powershell.exe if you intend to use variables,

```
powershell -Command "$local = Get-LocalUser; $local.Name; if ('Administrator' -in $local.Name) { 'Do Something' } else { 'Administrator Not Found' }"
```